# Help with the proof that a sequence is convergent iff it is bounded and has a single subsequential limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let $\{x_n\}$ denote a sequence for $n \in \Bbb N$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent if and only if it is bounded and has a single subsequential limit.

---

Let $P$ denote "a sequence is convergent" and $Q$ denote "is bounded and has a single subsequential limit". We want to prove two things:
$$
P\implies Q \tag1
$$
$$
Q \implies P \tag2
$$

---

$\Box$ Start with $(1)$. Bu definition of a limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N_\epsilon \in \Bbb N:\forall n > N_\epsilon \implies |x_n - a| < \epsilon
$$
Take for instance $\epsilon = 1$:
$$
|x_n - a| < \epsilon, \forall n > N_\epsilon
$$

But also:
$$
|x_n| - |a| < \epsilon \iff |x_n| < |a| + \epsilon
$$

Now take some $M$:
$$
M = \max\{1+|a|, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N\}
$$

That would give:
$$
\forall n \in \Bbb N: |x_n| \le M
$$

Which proves the sequence must be bounded. We also need to show that it has a uniq limit, which is pretty straightforward by contradiction (not posting it here) $\Box$

---

The second part is where I got stuck. I need to somehow show that $Q\implies P$, but not sure if the below is correct. Here are some thoughts.

$\Box$ Suppose that there is a single subsequential limit. Denote the subsequence as $\{x_{n_k}\}$:
$$
\lim_{{n_k}\to \infty} x_{n_k} =  L
$$

We need to show that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = L
$$

Suppose the opposite:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = C \ne L
$$

We know that $x_n$ is bounded, therefore there are such $a$ and $b$ that all the terms of $x_n \in [a, b]$.

Split $[a, b]$ into two equal parts. At least one of them contains infinitely many terms of $x_n$. Denote this interval as $[a_1, b_1]$. Let $x_{n_1} \in [a_1, b_1]$.

Split $[a_1, b_1]$ into two parts. One of them contains infinitely many terms. Denote this interval $[a_2, b_2]$. Chose $x_{n_2} \in [a_2, b_2]$ such that $n_2 > n_1$. Repeating that infinitely many times we have a set of intervals $[a_k ,b_k]$ and a set of terms from $x_n$ such that $x_{n_k}\in [a_k, b_k]$ and $n_{k_1} > n_{k_2}$ when $k_1 > k_2$.

From the above if follows that $x_{n_k}$ satisfies the definition of a subsequence of $x_n$. Also:
$$
b_k - a_k = \frac{b-a}{2^k} \to 0\ \text{as} \ k \to \infty
$$

Which means there exist at least one point $C$ that belongs to all intervals. Taking the limit and using squeeze theorem for $a_k < b_k$ we get:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = \lim_{k\to\infty}b_k = C \\
a_k \le x_{n_k} \le b_k
$$

And thus:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = \lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k} = \lim_{k\to\infty}b_k = C
$$

Which contradicts the assumption that only one subsequential limit exists. Hence indeed:
$$
Q \implies P
$$
$\Box$

I would appreciate if someone could approve/reject the reasoning above. Thank you!

Comment: What you call the opposite isn't the opposite at all.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Well, then i believe the whole argument for at least $(2)$ is wrong

Comment: Does the single substantial limit mean that all the subsequences of $a_n$ are convergent to one limit?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz yes, that’s true