# Show that a bounded sequence having one limit point is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a bounded sequence having one limit point is convergent.

The converse holds true. The fact that a convergent seq is bounded has been shown in Baby Rudin. The fact that it will have only one limit point can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386703/prove-that-a-convergent-sequence-has-only-one-limit-point-proof-verification/3386711?noredirect=1#comment6967723_3386711).

The similar question seems to have been asked before on MSE except that there is no complete or well-detailed solution.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1552411/27978

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035671/27978

Comment: Maybe you could search a little?

Comment: The second link contains the proof to the converse, which already exists in the link I provided. The proof in the first link that deals with the right-to-left direction (which is what I require) of the statement given, isn't complete, I feel.

Comment: You need more hypotheses. If I take the space $[0,1)$ and the sequence $0,1-{1 \over 2},0,1-{1 \over 3},0,1-{1\over 4},...$ then the sequence is bounded, has a single limit point but is not convergent.

Comment: Indeed. But it is convergent if we consider $\mathbb{R}$. (Side question : can there be a convergent seq without a limit point? Because, if $p$ is the limit of the seq, then $p \in \mathcal{X}$ and clearly there are infinitely many points in any open neighbourhood of $p$ which makes $p$ a limit pt as well. The use of "at most one lt pt" in the first link doesn't make sense, right?)

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I feel that there should be additional conditions to my statement, which I cannot think of. Could you help me out with that? For instance, your seq is convergent if the space we considered had been $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does this make sense : A real sequence (with space $\mathbb{R}$) that is bounded and has one limit point, is convergent.

Comment: I am going to remove some of my misleading statements above. What do you mean by a limit point of a sequence? (As opposed to a set.)

Comment: I added a proof below.

Comment: Did my answer address your concerns?

Comment: I did. I'm not aware of compact sets, which is why I did not comment further on that. I'll have a look into it again by tomorrow and let you know. Thank you so much for the same!

Comment: Review your real analysis, compactness is central to many things. The main point here is that a sequence contained in a compact set always has a limit point. In the reals compactness is equivalent to closed and bounded (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and has exactly one limit point. Then
$x_n$ converges.

Suppose $x_{n_k} \to x$, and suppose $|x_n| \le B$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then $C_\epsilon=[-B,x-\epsilon] \cup [x+\epsilon,B]$ is a compact set, hence at most a finite number of $x_n \in C_\epsilon$ (otherwise there would be another limit point).

In particular, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, we have $|x-x_n| < \epsilon.$ Hence $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Right. Makes so much sense now. I had to look up a couple of things, for instance, the Theorem 2.37 of Baby Rudin (If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$) which I were not aware of all this while. I am trying to learn sequences without having any idea of topology. Would it be beneficial to read topology alongside or it is fine to just learn sequences first?

Comment: I would learn the topology as well. The notion and implications of open sets takes a while to become familiar with in the context of real analysis.

Comment: Apparently, yes. Thank you so much for all this!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. After 3 decades, I still am regularly confounded by real analysis. It is wonderful but shows no mercy :-).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\limsup x_{n}=\lim_{k}x_{n_{k}}$ and $\liminf x_{n}=\lim_{l}y_{n_{l}}$ for some subsequences of $(x_{n_{k}})$ and $(y_{n_{l}})$ of $(x_{n})$, so by assumption $\lim_{k}x_{n_{k}}=\lim_{l}y_{n_{l}}$, so the limit exists.